# Refused to apply style from 'https://localhost:4200/styles.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported SS

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, angular-cli

In my Angular + .NET Core application, whenever I try to execute my application, I am seeing this error in Chrome browser developer tools Console Tab.

This is my angular.JSON file

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "client": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {},
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/client",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "aot": true,
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
             
            ]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb",
                  "maximumError": "10kb"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "sslKey": "./SSL/server.key",
            "sslCert": "./SSL/server.crt",
            "ssl": true,
            "browserTarget": "client:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "client:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "client:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              
            ]
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "tsconfig.app.json",
              "tsconfig.spec.json",
              "e2e/tsconfig.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        },
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "client:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "client:serve:production"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "client",
  "cli": {
    "analytics": "1e289159-497d-4b77-9821-d86621a15f6b"
  }
}
```

and my index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>Maanavar - Kalvi</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" name="viewport">
  
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">  
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ionicons/4.1.2/collection/icon/icon.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/admin-lte/2.4.3/css/AdminLTE.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/admin-lte/2.4.3/css/skins/skin-blue.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet"href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,600,700,300italic,400italic,600italic">
  <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/js/all.js" integrity="sha384-xymdQtn1n3lH2wcu0qhcdaOpQwyoarkgLVxC/wZ5q7h9gHtxICrpcaSUfygqZGOe" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.13.0/css/all.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  
  

</head>

<body class="hold-transition skin-blue sidebar-mini">

    <app-root></app-root>

  <!-- Add the sidebar's background. This div must be placed
    immediately after the control sidebar -->
    <div class="control-sidebar-bg"></div>
    </div>


   
  <!-- Script Section -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> <!-- REQUIRED JS SCRIPTS -->  
    <!-- AdminLTE App -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/admin-lte/2.4.3/js/adminlte.min.js"></script>
  <!-- End of Script Section -->
</body>

</html>
```

I checked other questions in the site with same query but those solutions are not resolving my error in the application. So Could someone look into my code and help me finding the way to resolve this. Thanks

Comment: Probably not a code issue. More likely a server issue not setting correct mimetype

Comment: @MikeOne How to set that